# Implement push messaging in a Hybrid Web / Mobile App? (capacitor -> Quasar Framework; Vue.js)

Tags: service-worker, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor, quasar-framework

I am developing a hybrid mobile app with quasar framework / **vue.js** and **capacitor** builds it for android / iOS. I am successfully using plugins like a barcode scanner using the phones camera or device files access, but I also want to enable a working *push notification background process*.

I already tried implementing **firebase** as a **service worker**, but that only worked out on the desktop dev environment - on mobile it won't even load the service worker or react to it.

So, what would be the best way to do that? How can i enable my hybrid app to listen to requests from firebase or any other cloud messaging service?

We use **RabbitMQ** as our main message broker - in the end the app should be able to react to it.

Thanks for your help!!